# How to fetch from graphql server using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, graphql

#### How I can get response from graphql server using pure js without libraries?

For example how I can do that using `XMLHttpRequest`?
Query and serverUrl are below:

```
const serverUrl = 'http://example.com/graphql/'
const query = {
    query: `{
        viewer {
            date
        }
    }`
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use `POST` request with `'Content-Type', 'application/json'`

```js
const yourServerUrl = 'http://example.com/graphql'
const yourQuery = {
    query: `{
        users {
            firstName
        }
    }`
};

// below ordinary XHR request with console.log
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('POST', yourServerUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('data returned:', xhr.response);
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(yourQuery));
```

[source](https://medium.com/@seanchatman/basic-graphql-with-vue-and-plain-javascript-f4ec2127e1f0)